# How to set textbox value to variable to use in match function VBA

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I want to let a user input a string into a text box on a user form. I then want to compare that value to a range in a table.

I try to set the textbox value to a variable and it tells me I an "Object is required".

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim NwIns As TextBox
Dim tblm As Range
Dim c As TextBox

Set tblm = Worksheets("Main Committee Database").ListObjects("CredDB").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange
UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus
Set c = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

If IsNumeric(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(c, tblm, 0)) = True Then

MsgBox "This Vendor Already Exists"

Else
```

Comment: That seemed to be the right change but opened up another issue. It says its unable to get the Match property of the worksheet function class.

Comment: Is there a better way to use the error as T/F match?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `C` as a textbox you can't assign a string value to it.

```
Dim c as Control
Set c = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox1")
```

Or you could do

```
Dim c as string
c = UserForm1.TextBox1
```

But if you want to do anything to that textbox, like clear it after, it's best to just get the object itself instead of the value.

`application.worksheetfunction.match` will error if doesn't match. You could use error handling instead of your if statement but that isn't a great way to deal with it. A better way is to use `.find` and then check if it actually found anything.

All together:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim NwIns As TextBox
Dim tblm As Range
Dim c As Control
Dim fndrng As Range

Set tblm = Worksheets("Main Committee Database").ListObjects("CredDB").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange
UserForm1.TextBox1.SetFocus

Set c = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox1")
Set fndrng = tblm.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) 'You may want to play with those parameters to meet your needs.

If Not fndrng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "This Vendor Already Exists"

Else
```

Comment: I like the find much better. When I run this, I get a type mismatch when setting c = userfom1.textbox1...

Comment: Heh, should be fixed now. Should have tested with an actual textbox I assumed that would work.

Comment: Never mind. I re-pasted and tried again and it works fine. Thank you.